# Open source well designed play-scala-slick application

Tags: scala, design-patterns, playframework, open-source, slick

I am learning Scala, Play and Slick. Can you point me to some well written open source applications that I can use to better use these tools?

Thanks

Comment: For `Slick` there are a number of activator templates [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/?query=activator-slick), related to play there are some example applications in the Play-Slick plugin github page [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples).

Comment: VirtusLab also has a forked [template](https://github.com/VirtusLab/activator-play-advanced-slick) you may want to look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fully automatic Play Slick CRUD app

- https://github.com/slick/play-slick-codegen
- Corresponding talk: http://www.parleys.com/play/53a7d2c6e4b0543940d9e54c/

Activator templates:

- https://typesafe.com/activator/templates#filter:slick

Some third-party Slick apps:

- https://github.com/SlickChair/SlickChair
- https://github.com/happymelly/teller

Lots of community related work:
https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/826/files